# How to retrieve String from a spinner using array?

Tags: android, arrays, toast, android-spinner

I added arrays on the `string.xml`, and these strings are visible in my `Spinner` when I run the app. The problem is that the `Toast` does not display the value of the gender variable.

I made a separate class for this because I will also use `Spinners` for *birthmoth*, *birthdate* and *birthyear*.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    //SPINNERS
    spinner_gender = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.reg_gender);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.array_gender, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_gender.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner_gender.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
```

---

```
    public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener
{

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
        View view, int pos, long id) 
    {
        genderString = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) 
    {
      // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Toast` will not appear if you don't call the method `show()` on it:

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: A late "Thank you" for you, sir. I'm such a newbie programmer. /sigh

Comment: @JetPro No problem. For future projects also remember that the dialogs also require the `show()` method to be called:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

`Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), 
        "OnItemSelectedListener : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`


OR.. Simply you can use

`Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Your Toast message in here",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`